# web api routing

Tags: routes, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have the following url:

localhost/api/machine/somecode/all

I have the following controller:

```
 public class MachineController : ApiController
{
    public IEnumerable<Machine> Get()
    {
        return new List<Machine>
                   {
                       new Machine
                           {
                               LastPlayed = DateTime.UtcNow,
                               MachineAlertCount = 1,
                               MachineId = "122",
                               MachineName = "test",
                               MachinePosition = "12",
                               MachineStatus = "test"
                           }
                   };
    }

    public IEnumerable<Machine> All(string code)
    {
        return new List<Machine>
                   {
                       new Machine
                           {
                               LastPlayed = DateTime.UtcNow,
                               MachineAlertCount = 1,
                               MachineId = "122",
                               MachineName = "test",
                               MachinePosition = "12",
                               MachineStatus = "test"
                           }
                   };
    }
}
```

and the following routes:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
          name: "MachineApi",
          routeTemplate: "api/machine/{code}/all"
      );

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );


    }
}
```

but for some reason it's not resolving - any glaringly obvious reason why?

Answer (score 2):

Yeah by using the Method name All you are inferring an Action, you also need to indicate the controller to match to so this would probably work:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
      name: "MachineApi",
      routeTemplate: "api/machine/{code}/all",
      defaults: new { Action = "All", Controller = "Machine" }
  );
```

Comment: hi - thanks for that - unfortunately the URLs are set in stone from a legacy service :\

Comment: Hi. Fair enough, but my first part should allow your other approach to work. Updated to remove advise.

Answer (score 0):

Where is it getting code from in this line?

```
 routeTemplate: "api/machine/{code}/all"
```

I am assuming that is the route thats failing.

Do you not need a `defaults:` setting?

In fact wouldn't this default to:

```
 api/machine/all/{code}
```

Have you tried looking in the Net tab on Firefox? This will tell you the route that its tried to go to.